# Repeated values in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have a dataframe in pyspark where i have three columns

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 3, 4.2),
    ('a', 7, 4.2),
    ('b', 7, 2.6),
    ('c', 7, 7.21),
    ('c', 11, 7.21),
    ('c', 18, 7.21),
    ('d', 15, 9.0),
], ['model', 'number', 'price'])
df1.show()
+-----+------+-----+
|model|number|price|
+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     3|  4.2|
|    a|     7|  4.2|
|    b|     7|  2.6|
|    c|     7| 7.21|
|    c|    11| 7.21|
|    c|    18| 7.21|
|    d|    15|  9.0|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Is there a way in pyspark to display only the values that are repeated in the column 'price'?

like in df2 :

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 3, 4.2),
    ('a', 7, 4.2),
    ('c', 7, 7.21),
    ('c', 11, 7.21),
    ('c', 18, 7.21),
], ['model', 'number', 'price'])
df2.show()
+-----+------+-----+
|model|number|price|
+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     3|  4.2|
|    a|     7|  4.2|
|    c|     7| 7.21|
|    c|    11| 7.21|
|    c|    18| 7.21|
+-----+------+-----+
```

I tried to do this, but didn't work

```
df = df1.groupBy("model","price").count().filter("count > 1")
df2 = df1.where((df.model == df1.model) & (df.price == df1.price))
df2.show()
```

it included the values that are not repeated too

```
+-----+------+-----+
|model|number|price|
+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     3|  4.2|
|    a|     7|  4.2|
|    b|     7|  2.6|
|    c|     7| 7.21|
|    c|    11| 7.21|
|    c|    18| 7.21|
|    d|    15|  9.0|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with a window function. We partition by price, take a count and filter `count > 1`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

w = Window().partitionBy('price')

df1.withColumn('_c', f.count('price').over(w)).filter('_c > 1').drop('_c').show()

+-----+------+-----+
|model|number|price|
+-----+------+-----+
|    a|     3|  4.2|
|    a|     7|  4.2|
|    c|     7| 7.21|
|    c|    11| 7.21|
|    c|    18| 7.21|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm a beginner in pyspark so i didn't thought about window partitioning but i think it can work with group by also, it's just that i didn't put the condition where it must be, but again i'll try with your solution to get used to window function